# How do I wrap a C++ interface (abstract class) in C++/CLI?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, native

I have some C++ code:

```
namespace Compute {   
  class __declspec(dllexport) IProgressCB {   
  public:     
    virtual void progress(int percentCompleted) = 0;   
  };    
  double __declspec(dllexport) compute(IProgressCB *progressCB, ...); 
}
```

that I need to call from C#.
Therefore I want to wrap this C++ code in C++/CLI.

I understand how to wrap the compute() function,
but how do I wrap the IProgress interface?

(It seems it is not possible for a .Net class to inherit a C++ class?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This framework should get you started:

```
interface class IProgressEventSink
{ ... };

class ProgressEventForwarder : IProgressEventCB
{
    gcroot<IProgressEventSink^> m_sink;
public:
    ProgressEventForwarder(IProgressEventSink^ sink) : m_sink(sink) {}

// IProgressEventCB implementation
    virtual void OnProgress( ProgressInfo info ) { m_sink->OnProgress(info.a, info.b); }
};

ref class ComputeCLI
{
     Compute* m_pimpl;
 // ...

public:
     RegisterHandler( IProgressEventSink^ sink )
     {
         // assumes Compute deletes the handler when done
         // if not, keep this pointer and delete later to avoid memory leak
         m_pimpl->RegisterHandler(new ProgressEventForwarder(sink));
     }
};
```

Comment: BTW. Do you know how I can "automate" the construction of the Sink and the Forwarder code?

Comment: @Andreas: "construction of code" isn't very clear.  Do you mean "code generation" or "object construction"?

Comment: Sorry. I mean code generation. I understand that SWIG generate PInvoke code instead of C++/CLI, but something like that, perhaps more lightweight would be ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `ref class` which holds a pointer to the wrapped instance:

```
namespace ComputeCLI {
    public ref class IProgressCB{
    public:
        void progress(int percentCompleted)
        {
            // call corresponding function of the wrapped object
            m_wrappedObject->progress(percentCompleted);
        }

    internal:
       // Create the wrapper and assign the wrapped object
       IProgressCB(Compute::IProgressCB* wrappedObject) 
            : m_wrappedObject(wrappedObject){}

        // The wrapped object
        Compute::IProgressCB* m_wrappedObject;
    };

    public ref class StaticFunctions{
    public:
        static double compute(IProgressCB^ progressCB, ...){
            Compute::compute(progressCB->m_wrappedObject, ...);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I already have a C++ class called IProgressCB that will be included from C++/CLI; so this class must be called something else (e.g. IProgressCLI)? Also the compute() method expects a pointer to a C++ IProgress so IProgressCLI musth inherit IProgressCB, but this does not appear to be allowed?

Comment: You should consider to put your wrapper code into another namespace. (maybe ComputeCli) Thus, you are able to use the same function and class names. The compute function must work with the managed Interface. I will edit the code to demonstrate this.

Comment: But how do I tell my C++ code to invoke the C++/CLI interface? The "flow" here: C++->C++/CLI->C# is the opposite of what usually happens: C#->C++/CLI->C++.

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was too quick. The key is, that every wrapper class must know its native equivalent. Wrapper functions have to call the corresponding functions of the wrapped objects.
I changed the example above this way.

Comment: Yes but here it is the other way around; the wrapped object is trying to call the corresponding function of the wrapper. First off: Compute::IProgressCB is abstract so it can not be instansiated, there must be a sub class of it (?). Second: when the C++ code calls m_wrappedObject->progress(..) this is not forwarded to ComputeCLI::IProgressCB::progress()? If so how?

Comment: First: Yes there must be a public subclass this way. Otherwise, implement `progress` to call `progress` on the wrapped object.

Second: I'm not sure what your intention is. Why do you want to call the managed API?